# Mysql Select Id in with And operator

Tags: mysql, where-clause, and-operator

I want to get data from table where Id should be as given below in the query but instead of or I would apply and operator so lets say ID IN (5 AND 4 AND 3)

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (5,4,3,1,6)
```

Is it possible to get data like this.

This is the sample query

```
SELECT PM.ContentID, PM.Author, PM.Title, PM.Journal, PM.Year, PM.Category, PM.StudyLocation, PM.FileURL from PublishedContentMaster PM join  TopicContentMapping T ON T.ContentID=PM.ContentID where PM.ContentID='100' AND T.TopicID IN (16,7)
```

So I want which is present in both 16 and 17 that is why I need and operator not or.

Comment: Please show sample data and desired results.

Comment: How can ID have value 5,4,3,1,6 at the same time? At a given instance, ID can have any single value, not all. Your question is not clear. Kindly rephrase it.

Comment: @MoishKamble I am using filter so lets say I select Topic One it will only search on ID one and if I select two or more than it will work vice versa

Comment: Thats exactly how `OR` works. Can you show the output of the query and the expected output.

Comment: @MoishKamble Output is simple showing ContentID : 1 Author : Ali Title: Test Journal : A Year: 2012 Category : A. So I want that if this is only in Topic ID 16 it should not be showing when we provide 16 and 17 both in TopicID

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you want an aggregation query and a `having` clause.  It would typically look something like this:

```
select x
from t
where id in (5, 4, 3, 1, 6)
group by x
having count(*) = 5;
```

In this case, `x` would be the column where you want five rows with the five values.